# swift make XML using codingkeys

Tags: swift, xml

I have many models.  One example is

```
struct Person
{
  let id = Int
  let nameOfBoss = String
...
}
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
{
  case id
  case nameOfBoss = "nam_of_boss"
...
}
```

I want to make XML.  The web service reads code like (snake_case)

```
...
<name_of_boss>Greg</name_of_boss>
...
```

How can I make XML, using the codingKeys rawValue (String) to make like above?

(I haven't had success with most pods - so I avoid them now. Although managed to use SWXMLHash)

(I wrote some code that would create an object mirror...but it won't use the rawValue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your `CodingKey` in the serialization process, you probably want to use the new `Codable` protocol, but Foundation does not support XML.

Shawn Moore wrote an [interesting library](https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing) that adds the missing, from the Foundation, `XMLDecoder` and `XMLEncoder` classes. (`Codable` support for XML) Although it does not have a readme file, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50823912/6791677) can help you about how to use it.

Another solution is to try [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper). This library uses the same idea as [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) but for XML.

For example you can serialize the following model struct:

```
struct Person: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String! = "Person"

    var id: String?
    var nameOfBoss: String?

    init() {

    }

    init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    mutating func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        id <- map["id"]
        nameOfBoss <- map["nam_of_boss"]
    }
}
```

To the following XML:

```
<Person>
    <id>1</id>
    <nam_of_boss>Greg</nam_of_boss>
</Person>
```

Using `toXMLString()` function of the `XMLMappable` protocol:

```
var person = Person()
person.nameOfBoss = "Greg"
person.id = "1"
let xmlString = person.toXMLString()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have implemented your first suggestion and it makes xml good.  (I am unable to create the retrieve function - but that's not needed).  Do you happen to know how I can put a static xmlns in the xml?

Comment: Actually this is something that I am interested in too.

`XMLMapper` do have the `data(withXMLObject:addXMLDeclaration:)` function in `XMLSerialization` that does exactly this, but is done by just appending a static string in front of the other XML.
I would like to improve this in some way.

Comment: Just what I added:<pre>

 func toXML(header: XMLHeader, wrapper: String? = nil, wrapperNS: String? = nil) -> String?
 {
  ...
  do
  {
   let data = try encoder.encode(self, withRootKey: "customer")
   let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
   return header.toXML()! + ((wrapper != nil) ? "<\(wrapper!)" + ((wrapperNS != nil) ? " \(wrapperNS!)>\n" : ">\n") : "") + str! + ((wrapper != nil) ? "\n</\(wrapper!)>" : "")
  }
  ...
 }`

then

 xml = result.toXML(header: XMLHeader(version: 1.0, encoding: "UTF-8"), wrapper: "mystuff", wrapperNS: "xmlns:xlink=\"http://...\"")</pre>